# Amazon Redshift - Hash table for subplan does not exist

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a view in Amazon Redshift that worked properly for several month. One day all of a sudden it stopped working with an error:

```
error:  Assert
code:      1000
context:   ht0_3 != NULL - Hash table for subplan does not exist.
```

The query itself has 3 CTEs each selecting distinct rows from a single table. They are then joined together. Each CTE works fine by itself, but when I try to join them I get this error (although before it worked just fine)

Internet has close to 0 information on this error. The error can be avoided if I leave one of CTEs out of join, but I need that info in the resulting table.

UPD: I managed to solve the problem, but I still have no idea why the error happened. Below is the query that was causing problems and rewritten version that works.

```
CREATE TABLE bad_table AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        t.table_schema,
        t.table_name,
        t.column_name
    FROM svv_columns t
    WHERE true
        AND t.table_name not like '%test%'
        AND t.table_schema in ('table_1','table_2', ... , 'table_30')
)
```

However, the query rewritten in the following way works just fine:

```
CREATE TABLE failing_table AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        t.table_schema,
        t.table_name,
        t.column_name
    FROM svv_columns t
    WHERE true
        AND t.table_name not like '%test%'
        AND (t.table_schema in ('table_1', ... , 'table_10')
            or t.table_schema in ('table_11', ... , 'table_20')
            or t.table_schema in ('table_21', ... , 'table_30'))
    )
```

What is interesting, is that the failing AND condition was used in two separate CTEs. In one CTE it worked (it had 30 table enumerated in the `in` clause and some more) and in the other one (where the same 30 table are the only present) it fails.

To sum up, here are the two questions I would appreciate to hear an explanation for:

1. How could it be that the VIEW was working fine for month and all of a sudden started throwing this error. No changes were made to the DB setting or the VIEW itself.
2. Why would the same AND condition fail in a case when all `in` conditions are enumerated together, but works fine when they are joined by `or` operator.

Comment: Can you post the SQL and EXPLAIN plan for your query?

Comment: This looks like a database config/setup issue. Maybe you can get better answers at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @TheImpaler maybe, but no changes to the DB config were made. I am gonna leave the question here, as the problem was solved, but no need to transfer it to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun with query compilers.

First off the query shouldn't throw an error and likely has been introduced by an update to your Redshift cluster.  Check to see if an update happened around when an RS version changed happened.  AWS should be informed of the error.  You can also roll back the version if you want solid proof or need this to be resolved.  Redshift code is updated regularly and sometimes bugs slip in.

When you run any query every database compiles and optimizes the query to provide the fastest execution time.  You write the query one way but the database decides to execute it in a different way.  This is normal.  Redshift has several different optimizers (optimization methods) that is can choose from and makes that choice based on a number of factors (table meta data, query syntax, ... , and an AI learning process).  So this AI could be what introduced the change but I'd suspect code update first.

Now to your exact code.  I've seen this before - IN list length is a factor in how the optimizer organized your code.  Short IN lists will be changed to an OR list of equality checks [X IN ('A', 'B') will be changed to X = 'A' OR X = 'B'].  It does this because it is faster to execute.  For longer IN lists Redshift will set up a data structure with all the elements in it (like a pseudo-table) and perform a join-like operation to make the comparison.  For long lists of values, this is faster.  When I last debugged and issue like this with a client and AWS the break point was around 10 values in the IN list but that was a few years ago.

So, I suspect, your revised code works because you have a long IN list which causes the optimizer to make different choices and avoid the introduced bug.  This, of course, is speculation but based on experience with similar issues.  You can compare the EXPAIN plans for the two queries and I expect you will see that they are planned differently due to optimizer choices.